# What steps are involved to derive a functional expression for the revolving line of a cooling tower?

Tags: calculus, functions, solid-of-revolution

I am in my second year of International Baccalaureate diploma program. I have chosen to evaluate the integral expression of the Cooling Tower numerically and analytically for my Internal Assessment from Mathematics HL. So far, I have succeeded in performing indirect measurement of a cooling tower from a photograph, transforming measurements into real dimensions using scale factor and numerically evaluating definite integral by Trapezoidal rule.

I am having difficulties in modeling two functions of hyperbolas joined in a common vertex. I have transformed a standard form into general equation of hyperbola and solved for x. However, in my case, the final result differs with the one I have found in [cooling-tower handout](http://brianveitch.com/calculus2/handouts/cooling-tower.pdf). Thus, I would like to ask you for an explanation or at least hints how to get the equation of the right branch of the hyperbola.

My [calculations](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sQZortTiLH6rqz2g7-HfH_VgFU39l8dgIv4aT3PnH9E/edit?usp=sharing)

Thank you.

Comment: $x=-\sqrt{a^2+by^2}$, don't you think ?

Comment: If you open the cooling tower handout, then you will see that the cooling tower can be created by rotating the equation without minus sign around the y axis. In the calculations document I tried to solve it for x, but could not get it in that exact form. Thank You for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that $a$ and $b$ are just arbitrary constants, and falsely assuming that they must labeled by the same letters at all times. You have correctly calculated that if $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} - \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$ then the right branch of the hyperbola (i.e., the one with $x > 0$) is given by $$x = \frac ab\sqrt{b^2 + y^2}$$

But let's bring that $\frac ab$ inside:
$$x = \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{b^2}(b^2 + y^2)} = \sqrt{a^2 + \frac{a^2}{b^2}y^2}$$

Now let's define $c = \frac {a^2}{b^2}$. Then we have $$x = \sqrt{a^2 + cy^2}$$
which is identical to the equation in the handout, except for using $c$ instead of $b$. And that is your answer. The value you labeled $b$ is not the same as the value labeled $b$ in the handout.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing full explanation to the problem I've been having so much difficulties with.